# Griffiths' Electrodynamics: Understanding force of repulsion between two hemispheres of uniformly charged sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Consider the following problem from Griffiths's *Electrodynamics*

> **Problem 2.42** A metal sphere of radius $R$ carries a total charge $Q$. What is the force of repulsion between the "northern hemisphere
> and the "southern" hemisphere?

Though it is not stated, I believe it is implicit that the charge is uniformly distributed, with constant charge density $\sigma$.

**Here is my understanding of the problem**

We know the electric field generated by the sphere because of Gauß's theorem.

$$\oint_{G.S} \vec{E}\cdot\hat{\vec n}\,\mathrm dS=E\,4\pi r^2=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}\tag{1}$$

where G.S. stands for Gaußian surface (a sphere of radius $r$ around the charged sphere). If we use $\sigma=\frac{Q}{4\pi R^2}$ then

$$E=\left(\frac Rr\right)^2\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\tag{2}$$

for $r\geq R$ and so for $r=R$ we have

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\tag{3}$$

In addition, we can show that the electric field inside the metallic sphere is zero.

Now, consider an infinitesimal patch of surface on, say, the northern hemisphere.

Using a Gaußian pillbox with top and bottom areas of $A$, of infinitesimal length above and below the surface, which we approximate as linear, we have

$$\int\limits_{\text{pillbox}} \vec{E}_{\text{patch}}\cdot \hat{\vec n}\,\mathrm dS=E_{\text{patch}}2A=\frac{q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}=\frac{\sigma A}{\epsilon_0}$$

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$$

This latter calculation takes into account only the electric field due to the small surface patch. Note that above the patch, we have

$$\vec{E}_{\text{patch,above}}=E_{\text{patch}}\hat{\vec r}$$
$$\vec{E}_{\text{patch,below}}=-E_{\text{patch}}\hat{\vec r}$$

However, the total field at the patch is actually

$$\vec{E}_{\text{above}}=\vec{E}_{\text{other}}+\vec{E}_{\text{patch,above}}$$
$$\vec{E}_{\text{below}}=\vec{E}_{\text{other}}+\vec{E}_{\text{patch,below}}$$

$\vec{E}_{\text{other}}$ is the electric field due to the rest of the sphere.

Hence,

$$\vec{E}_{\text{other}}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{E}_{\text{above}}+\vec{E}_{\text{below}})$$

$$=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{\vec r}$$

Now, we are interested in the electrostatic pressure on the surface which is given by the force per unit area on the surface,

$$\vec{f}=\sigma \vec{E}_{\text{other}}=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{\vec r}$$

**So at this point my question arises.**

Griffiths' solution manual says that we want

$$F_z=\int\limits_{\text{hemisphere}} f_z\,\mathrm da = \int \sigma \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \cos{\vartheta}\,R^2 \sin{\vartheta}\,\mathrm d\vartheta\,\mathrm d\varphi$$

I'm not sure I understand what this surface integral is computing.

If we were to take the surface integral of $\vec{E}_{\text{other}}$ over a hemisphere, then we would obtain a total force, because the surface integral is summing a force per area times an area.

Now, intuitively, by symmetry, the x and y components of these forces cancel if we consider the hemisphere as a whole.

So I guess, now after writing it out like this, that when we take the z component of $\vec{f}$ we are getting a force in the z-direction per area of hemisphere surface. And so when we take the integral we are getting just the total z component of the electrostatic force.

I guess my question at this point is if this reasoning is correct. I had never taken a surface integral of a component like this.

Comment: It is a metal sphere. The charge is automatically uniformly distributed. Your reasoning is correct. You are not looking for pressure, you are looking for a specific component of the force over the hemisphere.

Comment: Your arguments of the $E_\text{patch}$ and so forth are all wrong. On the surface the E field is $\sigma/\epsilon_0$ as you correctly obtained in Equation (3), and there is no field inside. What is really happening is that, over a very short distance near the surface, the E field rises from zero to the full E field, and essentially half the surface charge is inside, and half is outside, thus leading to the factor of a half.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say the field is zero inside, and then say that "half the surface charge is inside".

Comment: The relevant part in Griffiths is: "Let's focus our attention on a tiny patch of surface surrounding the point in question. (Make it small enough so it is essentially flat and the surface charge on it is essentially constant.) The total field consists of two parts - that attributable to the patch itself, and that due to everything else (other regions of the surface, as well as any external sources that my be present). Now, the patch cannot exert a force on itself, any more than you can lift yourself by standing in a basket and pulling up on the handles.

Comment: The force on the patch, then is due exclusively to $\vec{E}_{\text{other}}$, and this suffers no discontinuity (if we removed the patch the field in the "hole" would be perfectly smooth). The discontinuity is due entirely to the charge on the patch, which puts out a field $\sigma/2\epsilon_0$ on either side, pointing away from the surface."

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent by the way, what's with your edit of replacing Gauss with Gauß? I'm inclined to roll that change back. Also the author is David Griffiths. The possessive as far as I know can be Griffiths', as I had initially, or Griffiths's. I don't know if these edits were based on personal taste of the person who edited, but it is my question.

Comment: You had Griffith's, missing the s in the name. It is a fact that the E field is zero inside a conductor, and thus "the field is zero inside". As such, if you were to take Griffiths's argument totally seriously, then it will become a paradox because the charges elsewhere cannot be applying a force on the patch, because there is no E field for that to happen. Hence why I was appealing to deeper physics and analysing what really happens at a boundary, where we have to go beyond the zero-volume surface charge approximation.